# Retrieve AtTask Custom Form and Fields with entered data through API

Tags: attask

There are a couple of posts on retrieving custom forms with the AtTask API, but no responses actually seem to answer the question. I have a .NET console app that is using the REST API to query data, but there doesn't seem to be any object code (from here https://developers.attask.com/api-docs/api-explorer/) that is specific to custom forms and their fields. Am I missing something or is there some roundabout method to get to it?

edit: I've found out how to get the forms and their fields, but how do I get the values that have been entered into the form by users?

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but I'm also running into a problem getting a custom form and it's related fields since there are no objects or methods for custom forms.  Can you please share how to were able to get a custom form and fields?

Answer (score 3):

You can prefix the field with 'DE:', here is what I found at https://developers.attask.com/api-docs/#Basics

Custom Data

Custom data fields can also be retrieved by using the prefix "DE:". For instance, to request a project with a parameter called "CustomText" the following request could be made.

```
/attask/api/project/search?fields=DE:CustomText
```

which would return

```
{
    "name": "custom data project",
    "ID": "4c9a954f0000001afad0687d7b1b4e43",
    "DE:CustomText": "task b"
}
```

It is also possible to retrieve all the custom data for an object by requesting the parameterValues field.

```
/attask/api/project/search?fields=parameterValues
```

would might return something like

```
{
    "name": "custom data project",
    "ID": "4c9a954f0000001afad0687d7b1b4e43",
    parameterValues: {
        "DE:CustomText": "task b",
        "DE:CustomNumber": 1.4,
        "DE:CustomCheckBoxes": ["first", "second", "third"]
    }
}
```

Comment: While this answer helped, it doesn't answer the question as to how to retrieve data that was entered into a custom form.

Comment: So just retrieve it programmatically, deserialize the json and work with the values.